# Is it suitable to ask broad questions about localizations on StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions

I asked a question recently about localization in general (is a specific concept English only, or applied to other cultures/localization/languages as well, etc)

Is this suitable for StackOverflow?  I would think yes, but people objected to it otherwise, and wanted to ask the meta group what they thought.  I consider localization an important consideration for application development, but I know most people do.  Additionally, this is a very broad domain question I asked that isn't programming related, but programmers will probably deal with.

Question in question
[Are there other languages besides English that append suffixes to Arabic numerals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405028/are-there-other-languages-besides-english-that-append-suffixes-to-arabic-numerals)

Any input, comments?

Answer (score 2):

I would say yes, it goes on SO.

Strictly speaking it is indeed not programming, but you usually need to write some code to handle i18n and l10n. By knowing **what** you need to handle, you can then figure out what code you need to write.

In this case, asking lets you determine "is it worthwhile to add code to handle this, or can we just do a reasonable workaround for this one language so we don't need to handle it and can keep the code simpler". If you know that there's just this one language, and an entirely feasible workaround exists, it's probably not worth writing code for it - but it's a different case if there are several languages that require it.